# Vu3: forceUpdate() not working when used with async function

Tags: javascript, async-await, vuejs3

I have some code that deletes some data from firestore and then **should** reload the page.
It successfully operate on the database but fails to reload the page.

Here is my function `eliminaCategoria()`:

```
export async function eliminaCategoria(id, indexCategoria) {
    const ristorante = doc(db, "ristoranti", id);
    const docSnap = await getDoc(ristorante);
    let dati = docSnap.data();
    dati.categorie.splice(indexCategoria, 1);
    return await setDoc(ristorante, dati);
}
```

And here is where the function is called:

```
methods: {
    eliminaCategoria() {
      eliminaCategoria(this.idRisto, this.IndexArr).then(() => {
        this.$forceUpdate();
      });
    },
  }
```

Any ideas on how to solve the issue?

Thanks in advance, Lorenzo

Comment: Could you explain what you want update in Vue ? Shouldn't be there some response from function  and setup this value to your array?  Or you want just reload the page then  window.location.reload(); ?

Comment: I just want to reload the page

Comment: Then use window.location.reload()